# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt from Db

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security to perform a simple login and logout operation and all the users are stored in my database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFAMn.png)

the issue is everytime i try to log in i get an error saying "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt" but it encoded in my db.

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
public class UserController {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<User> getAllUser(){
        return userService.getAllUser();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getAllUserById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        return userService.getUserById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/email/{userEmail}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUserByUserEmail(@PathVariable ("userEmail") String userEmail){
        return userService.getUserByEmail(userEmail);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteUserById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        userService.removeUserById(id);
        return "User has been deleted Successfully";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateCoordinatorById(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable("id") long id){
        String pwd = user.getUserPassword();
        String encryptPwd = passwordEncoder.encode(pwd);
        user.setUserPassword(encryptPwd);
        userService.updateUser(user,id);
        return "User has been updated Successfully";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertCoordinator(@RequestBody User user){
        String pwd = user.getUserPassword();
        String encryptPwd = passwordEncoder.encode(pwd);
        user.setUserPassword(encryptPwd);
        userService.insertUser(user);
        return "User added Successfully";
    }
}
```

CustomerUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public  CustomUserDetailService(UserDao userDao){
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userDao.findUserByUserEmail(email);
        CustomUserDetail userDetail  =null;
        if(user !=null){
            userDetail= new CustomUserDetail();
            userDetail.setUser(user);
        }else{
            throw  new UsernameNotFoundException("user not exist with email: " +email);
        }
        return userDetail;
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetail.java

```
@Data
public class CustomUserDetail implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(r -> new
                SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+r)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getUserPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUserEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.user.getUserIsActive() == 1;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int userId;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userSurname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userOtherName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userEmail;
    private String userPassword;
    private int userIsActive;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public String getUserPassword(){
        return getUserSurname();
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public Collection<User> getAllUser(){
        return userDao.findAll();
    }
    public User getUserById(long id){
        return userDao.findById(id).get();
    }
    public void removeUserById(long id){
        userDao.deleteById(id);
    }
    public User updateUser(User user,long id){
        return userDao.findById(id).map(user1 -> {
            user1.setUserSurname(user.getUserSurname());
            user1.setUserOtherName(user.getUserOtherName());
            user1.setUserEmail(user.getUserEmail());
            user1.setUserPassword(user.getUserPassword());
            user1.setId(user.getId());
            user1.setUserId(user.getUserId());
            user1.setRoles(user.getRoles());
            return userDao.save(user1);
        }).orElseGet(() -> {
            user.setId(id);
            return userDao.save(user);
        });
    }

    public void insertUser(User user) {
        userDao.save(user);
    }
    public  User getUserByEmail(String email){
        return  userDao.findUserByUserEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that your `getPassword` method in your `User` returns the result of `getSurName` is propably the culprit.

Comment: So I’m trying to make the surname the password

Comment: Just remove the getter you added, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I remove it would it solve my BCrypt error

Comment: The whole getter doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Okay I would, can you now move to the main issue

Comment: That getter IS your main issue. First you are NOT encoding the password but the surname. Second the password that is stored is the encoded surname, but when doing a password check the unencoded surname is being used as a password. So the getter IS your main issue.

Comment: Yes I know I’m encoding the surname as the password that’s wat I want.

Comment: I give up... Apparently you aren't reading... The getter is the whole culprit as it will ALWAYS return the UNENCRYPTED surname as the password WHICH ISN"T bcrypt. Also from a security perspective this is basically the same as no security at all.

Comment: Did you checked the image I posted, a picture of how my dB looks like

Comment: Yes and you still haven't read my comments. The `getPassword` will always  return the unencrypted value... SO very nice that you have a column containing an encrypted value but that is pretty much useless as it is totally ignore, because of the simple fact that `getUserPassword` will **always** return the unencrypted surname. If you remove it it will return the encrypted value and should work. Your password encoding should change to use `getSurName` if you really want to use that as the password.

Comment: I want the default password of a new user to be his username, how do I go about that now

Comment: When creating a new user then call `getSurName` and encode that when setting the password. (Which I also stated in my previous comment).